# How to print an entire list while not starting by the first item

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to figure out how to print the following list while not starting by the first item. To be clear: If the list is `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, I want to print something like `4,5,6,7,8,0,1,2,3`

Here's the code:

```
you_can_move_on = False

List = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

next_player = 3

while not you_can_move_on:
    next_player = self.get_next_player_index(next_player)
    you_can_move_on = self.check_if_I_can_move_on
    print(next_player)


def get_next_player_index(self, i):
    if i == len(self.players):
        return 0
    else:
        return i+1

def check_if_I_can_move_on(self):
    return False
```

Comment: What problems/errors are you running into with the posted code?

Answer (score 9):

I think it should be

```
print(l[3:] + l[:3])
```

Comment: "next_player = 3" won't always be 3. I'm getting an error "list index out of range". I think the problem lies within the get_next_player_index function.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to rotate the players use a `deque` to cycle:

```
from collections import deque

d = deque([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

d.rotate(len(d)//2 + 1)

print(d)
deque([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

If you wanted to keep track of each player you could just keep rotating:

```
from collections import deque

d = deque([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

print(d)
next_p = d[0]
print(next_p)
d.rotate()
print(d)
next_p = d[0]
print(next_p)
```

Output:

```
deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
0
deque([8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
8
```

You can move the logic inside a `get_next_player` function, just make self.players a deque, this will automatically restart after all players have had a go starting with a different player each revolution:

```
def get_next_player(self):
    if self.players[0] is None:
        self.players.popleft()
        self.players.rotate(-1)
        self.players.appendleft(None)
     else:
        n_p = self.players[0]
        self.players.rotate()
    return n_p
```

The function takes care of the rotations, you can see the logic below:

```
# sim round
In [25]: print([get_next_player() for _ in range(10)])
[1, 0, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

In [26]: players 
# now next player starts
Out[26]: deque([None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0])
# sim round
In [27]: print([get_next_player() for _ in range(10)])
[2, 1, 0, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]

In [28]: players
Out[28]: deque([None, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1])
# next player starts
In [29]: print([get_next_player() for _ in range(10)])
[3, 2, 1, 0, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]

In [30]: players
Out[30]: deque([None, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: I still get the error "list index out of range".  I implemented it like this, can you spot a problem?:

 def get_next_player_index(self, i):
  if i == len(self.players):
   n_p = self.players[i]
   self.players.rotate()
   return n_p
  else:
   return i+1

Comment: @RageAgainstheMachine, you don't need to index anything, are your players not going sequentially? Also it is not possible you get a list error using a deque

Comment: its a poker game, the players are going "in order" but each turn theres a new "first player"

Comment: Then all you need to do is  rotate once when you finish so the start order moves to the next player, that is the advantage of a deque, you only need to rotate and pull the first player

Comment: I will edit the function to make it very simple to keep track

Comment: Appreciate all the help. To recap, I've got a list of 9 players (0-8) and I have the first one that is supposed to play (lets say its #4 (3) but once it reaches player 9 (8) it wont give me player 0,1,2 and that is where Im getting the the error. I'm not sure if I explained this properly, any thoughts on how to make my get_next_player function get ALL the players right up until the initial one (#4 (3))?

Comment: Just made the correction, got an error: "list indices must be integers, not None type"

Comment: @RageAgainstheMachine, forget indexing and i, the function will automatically do all the work, when each player has had a turn we start again but one player up from the last time i.e  player 0 starts first and is last one the next round etc...

Comment: In poker, a round can be broken down into 4 "waves". Preflop, flop, turn, river. During the Preflop wave, [3] starts, during all the other waves, its [1] that starts. Its a little tricky because you need some knowledge of texas holdem poker, or its possible I can't explain this properly.

Comment: I added a working example that hopefully makes it clear how the deque works, you can manipulate it to do whatever you want.